# What is the type of fragment in "Marina dove into the ocean depths, her tail slapping the surface dismissively"?

Tags: grammar, dependent-clause, sentence-fragments

What sort of a fragment is this?

> Marina dove into the ocean depths, her tail slapping the surface dismissively.

I want to know if this is a comma splice, or if it's actually correct. I don't think it's an adjective clause, but if it is, please add an explanation as to why.

Comment: It's an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).

Comment: It's not a fragment; it's called a *nominative absolute*.  This has been discussed before, but I didn't cite any one previous answer as a duplicate because I'm not sure which one would be the best explanation for you.  Type "nominative absolute" into the search box above and see if any of the answers you get are helpful.  If you still have questions after that, please ask them.

Comment: Yes, deadrat is absolutely right.  Listen to deadrat.  It's a nominative absolute.

Answer (score 1):

> *Marina dove into the ocean depths, her tail slapping the surface dismissively.*

There are two clauses.

The first clause is a complete sentence:

- *Marina dove into the ocean depths*

The second clause is a participle clause, with subject *her tail,* and verb phrase *slapping the surface dismissively.* This is an adverbial,
so it may be placed either at the beginning or the end.

- *Her tail slapping the surface dismissively, Marina dove into the ocean depths.*

As with most adverb clauses, there is the possibility of introducing it with a preposition or conjunction. Here the usual preposition would be *with*

- *Marina dove into the ocean depths, (with) her tail slapping the surface dismissively.*

*Nominative absolute* is not a helpful phrase. It's not used in syntax (*nominative* is reserved for noun case, and *absolute* doesn't mean anything in particular), but rather is a handwaving term that refers mostly to participles in ancient literary forms. A syntactician would simply say it's a participle.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is neither a fragment nor an instance of a comma splice. It is a complete sentence and is called a *nominative absolute*. If you enter "nominative absolute" into the search box on the upper right top of the page, you will find much more information, if needed.

Comment: Can you please explain what that is? And please give credit to the user who posted this "answer" in the comments. Namely, Deadrat.